# CodingBat sumNumbers

Tags: java, string

For this problem: http://codingbat.com/prob/p121193

I have written this code:

```
public int sumNumbers(String str) {
  int y = 0;
  int z = 0;
  for (int f4 = 0; f4 < str.length(); f4++) {
    if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(f4))) {
      for (int f5 = f4; f5 < str.length(); f5++) {
        if (!Character.isDigit(str.charAt(f5))) {
          z = (Integer.parseInt(str.substring(f4, f5)));
          y = y + z;
          f4 = f5 - 1;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return y;
}
```

These are the problems (they aren't code, but it refused to accept my question otherwise):

```
sumNumbers("abc123xyz") Expected: 123; Returned: 123
sumNumbers("aa11b33") Expected: 44; Returned: 11
sumNumbers("7 11") Expected: 18; Returned: 7
sumNumbers("Chocolate") Expected: 0; Returned: 0
sumNumbers("5hoco1a1e") Expected: 7; Returned: 7
sumNumbers("5$$1;;1!!") Expected: 7; Returned: 7
sumNumbers("a1234bb11") Expected: 1245; Returned: 1234
sumNumbers("") Expected: 0; Returned: 0
sumNumbers("a22bbb3") Expected: 25; Returned: 22
```

So to summarize, for some reason my code can't handle more than one number of more than one digit, and I have no idea why. I've been working on this on and off for a while, and while I refuse to look up answers directly, I could really use some help.
I'm in high school AP Comp. Sci.

Comment: The last line of your output of sumNumbers: You say expected is 25, returned 22...looks like the return should be 22? same for sumNumbers("s1234bb11") looks to be returning the right values to me. Can you describe the algorithm for what you expect? Nevermind. The codingbat link describes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. The only problem is that you are not handling the boundary conditions properly. You are checking whether `if (!Character.isDigit(str.charAt(f5)))`. Now, what if your inner while is exhausted and does not encounter this condition?

For Example, In case of the test cases failing for you, the last or the last few characters are integers.

See this, `aa11b33`. Now here, `33` will never be added to your sum i.e. `y` because your `if` condition never gets executed and inner while gets exhausted.

You need to handle the boundary conditions to recognize these valid inputs and then add them to the sum.

Here is the corrected code snippet for your reference:

```
public int sumNumbers(String str) {
  int y = 0, z = 0, f4, f5 = 0;
  for (f4 = 0; f4 < str.length(); f4++) {
    if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(f4))) {
      for (f5 = f4; f5 < str.length(); f5++) {
        if (!Character.isDigit(str.charAt(f5))) {
          z = (Integer.parseInt(str.substring(f4, f5)));
          y = y + z;
          f4 = f5;
          break;
        }
      }
      /* Handle Boundary Conditions */
      if (f4 != f5) {
          z = (Integer.parseInt(str.substring(f4, str.length())));
          y = y + z;
          break;
      }
    }
  }
  return y;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that there would actually need to have a character there to run operations on it. I have problems with good logic but forgetting a small detail a lot. Just a coincidence that it was all with numbers that had multiple digits.

Comment: Yes, But then that it what good problem setters and test makers do! :)

Comment: My problem was that I noticed it was all on the ones with multiple numbers, at least one of which had more than one digit, and I neglected to continue looking for other similarities, which is why I was so confused.

Comment: You did a great job. I was a lot worse when I started coding first.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code modified to handle the case where a valid number is found at the end of the String. I do think you could refactor this a bit to extract duplicate logic into a method and only calculate str.length() one time. But here it is and returns the results you expect:

```
    public int sumNumbers(String str) {
      int y = 0;
      int z = 0;

      for (int f4 = 0; f4 < str.length(); f4++) {
        Character c = str.charAt(f4);
        if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
          for (int f5 = f4; f5 < str.length(); f5++) {
            Character c2 = str.charAt(f5);

            if (!Character.isDigit(c2)) {
              z = (Integer.parseInt(str.substring(f4, f5)));
              y+= z;
              f4 = f5 - 1;
              break;
            }
            else if(Character.isDigit(c2) && f5 == str.length() -1){
                z = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(f4 ,str.length()));
                y += z;
                f4 = f5;
                break;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      return y;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing the output, we clearly see that numbers at the very end of the input string are ignored. All strings that have non-digits at the end are parsed correctly - for example "5$$1;;1!!" sums up to 7.

Looking at the inner for loop which looks for the length of an already recognized number, we can see that the loop ends before the inner conditional statement has a chance to sum it up.

The solution is to simply move the summing feature out of the inner loop:

```
public static int sumNumbers(String str) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int start = 0; start < str.length(); start++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(start))) {
            int end;
            for (end = start; end < str.length(); end++) {
                if (!Character.isDigit(str.charAt(end))) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            sum += (Integer.parseInt(str.substring(start, end)));
            start = end - 1;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Note that I renamed your variables a bit to make them more readable.

---

An alternative way for summing up is to use a [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/). I mention this because the for-loops look very complicated and the regular expression for this task is exceptionally readable.

```
// \d+ means numbers with a minimum of 1 character
// (...) makes it a group that can be referred to later
private static Pattern NUMBERS = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");

public static int sumNumbers(String str) {
    Matcher matcher = NUMBERS.matcher(str);
    int sum = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(matcher.group());
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution simply does not handle digits at the end of string. I would suggest a solution like this:

```
int y = 0;
int z = 0;
for (int f4 = 0; f4 < str.length(); f4++) {
    int f5 = 0;
    // forward while digits found
    for (f5 = f4; f5 < str.length() && Character.isDigit(str.charAt(f5)); f5++);
    // if found at least one digit parse it
    if(f5 > f4){
        z = (Integer.parseInt(str.substring(f4, f5)));
        y = y + z;
        f4 = f5 - 1;
    }
}
return y;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int sumNumbers(String str) {
    int y = 0;
    int z = 0;
    for (int f4 = 0; f4 < str.length(); f4++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(f4))) {
            for (int f5 = f4; f5 < str.length(); f5++) {
                if (!Character.isDigit(str.charAt(f5))) {
                    z = (Integer.parseInt(str.substring(f4, f5)));
                    y = y + z;
                    z = 0;
                    f4 = f5;
                    break;
                }
                if (!Character.isDigit(str.charAt(f5)) || f5 == (str.length() - 1)) {
                    z = (Integer.parseInt(str.substring(f4, f5 + 1)));
                    y = y + z;
                    z = 0;
                    f4 = f5;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return y;
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information in your answer, such as an explanation of why this code provides a good solution

Comment: In this code have two parts to find the number from the string.
if (!Character.isDigit(str.charAt(f5)) || f5 == (str.length() - 1)) {
                    z = (Integer.parseInt(str.substring(f4, f5 + 1)));
                    y = y + z;
                    z = 0;
                    f4 = f5;
                    break;
                }
handling if integer at the last of the string and other if handling rest integer number in the string. and in that Z is treating as temporary variable, so make it zero after every operation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can also be solved in another way.

```
 public int sumNumbers(String str) {
  int result=0;
  int firstPosOfDig=0;
  int LastPosOfDig=0;

  for(int i=0; i<str.length();i++)
  {
    if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i)))
    {
      if(i==0 || !Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i-1)))
        firstPosOfDig=i;
      if(i==str.length()-1 || !Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i+1)))
        {
          LastPosOfDig=i;
          result+=Integer.parseInt(str.substring( firstPosOfDig, LastPosOfDig+1));
        }
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```